# Create a cocoapods nexus repository

Tags: cocoapods, nexus

I have a nexus running (3.21.1). It works fine for most repositories I created. But when I create a cocoapod repo whit this minimal configuration

[repo config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCWJB.png)

It returns an error 404 when I try to access to the repo url (http://localhost:8081/repository/b/)

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I don't see anything here that tells me what you have done.  What platform?  What commands are you using?  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error ***and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself***. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

GET request to the root of the repository should return an error message with an explanation due to a bug, this explanation is no present in the last version. But it works if you don't point to the root of the repo

Comment: In other words, you can't browse NXRM like that, you have to use browse or search features :)